# Как остановить цикл если в dataframe кончились колонки?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, циклы, dataframe

Есть основной цикл1, который бежит по массиву большой длинны, в этом цикле выполняются цикл пробега по колонкам дата фрейма и там по некотором условиям удаляются эти самые колонки.

Есть ли такое условие, которое проверяет дата фрейм на содержание колонок, и чтобы в определённый момент, проверив это условие он увидел, что колонки кончились и нужно остановить основной цикл1.

```
import pandas as pd
# import sys
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


op=open('2.txt', 'w+')
with open("11.net", "r") as file:
    for line in ''.join(file.read().split('\n')).split(';'):
        #print(line)
        op.write(line)
        op.write('\n')
op.close()

fn = r'2.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(fn,  sep="~", names=['line'])
df[['узлы','data']]=df['line'].str.split(n=1,expand=True)
df = df.drop('line',1)
df['data']=df['data'].str.replace("(?:\([^\)]*\)|,)",' ')
new=df.set_index('узлы')['data'].str.get_dummies(' ')
file.close()

new2 = new
new2 = new2.drop('X1', 1)

color = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'y', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen', 'orange']
for c in color:
    print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++',c)
    k = 4
    k1 = 0
    v = 12
    v1 = 0
    #ищем макс элем для формирования с ним платы
    maxi=0

    print('n2', new2)
    for el in new2:
        #print('summa stolbca', new2[el].sum())
        maxel=new2[el].sum()
        if maxel > maxi:
            maxi=maxel
            first=el

    k1=k1+1# для будущей проверки на число элементов в узле

    new2=new2.drop(first, 1) #однёрка указывает на удаление столбца с таким именем

    print('max element=', first,'сумма единиц которого =', maxi)  #   название столбца максимальным элементом

    start_dict={}
    mid_dict={}
    final_dict={}
    mas_name=[]
    mas_znach=[]
    for kol_new2 in new2:
        konyoukt=new[first] & new2[kol_new2]
        znach_kon=konyoukt.sum() # VAZHNO
        mas_name.append((first, kol_new2))
        mas_znach.append(znach_kon)

    start_dict=dict(zip(mas_name, mas_znach)) #= массив со всеми возможными связями между
                                                                    # начальным элементом и остальными из D.F.
    print(start_dict)
    print('ищем макс знач конъюкции среди ', len(start_dict), ' элементов')



    while k1<k and v1<v:
        print('k1=',k1)
        print('v1=',v1)
        mid_dict={x: y for x, y in filter(lambda x: start_dict[x[0]] == max(start_dict.values()), start_dict.items())}
        if len(mid_dict)==1:
            #value=mid_dict[0]
            value=list(mid_dict.values())
            for n in value:
                n=int(n)
            print(n)
            if v1+n<=v:
                v1=v1+n
                k1=k1+1
                print('k1+1=', k1)
                print('v1+n=',v1)
                final_dict.update(mid_dict)
                keys=list(mid_dict.keys())

                print('МИД ДИКСТ ', mid_dict)
                print('FINAL_DICT ', final_dict)
                print('keys[0]', keys[0])
                print(keys[0][1])
                new2=new2.drop(keys[0][1], 1)
                start_dict.pop(keys[0])
                print('удалил элемент = ', keys[0] )
                print(new2)
                keys.clear()
        elif len(mid_dict)>1:
            print('mid_dikt===', mid_dict)
            print('if len>1')
            value = list(mid_dict.values())
            for si in value:
                si = int(si)
            print('наше число связей для всех элементов = ',si)
            if v1+si<=v:
                max_z=200
                for q in mid_dict:
                    print('q=', q[1])
                    dizyounk=new[first] | new2[q[1]]
                    sum_diz=dizyounk.sum()
                    if sum_diz<max_z:
                        max_z=sum_diz
                        iskomoe=q[1]
                        print(iskomoe)
                    print(sum_diz)
                mas_final=[(first, iskomoe)]
                #print(mid_dict)
                mid_dict=mid_dict.clear()
                mid_dict={(first, iskomoe): si}
                print('mid DIKT', mid_dict)
                start_dict.pop((first,iskomoe))
                print('new2=iskomoe=', new2[iskomoe])
                new2=new2.drop(iskomoe,1)

                final_dict.update(mid_dict)
                k1=k1+1
                v1=v1+si
                print('tut k1=', k1)
                print('tut v1=', v1)
                print(' tutFINAL DICT', final_dict)
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе ваш код. Обчно это делается несколько иначе - сначала получаем список ненужных столбцов и удаляем все одним махом или получаем список нужных и выбираем все одним махом...

Comment: @MaxU не могу скинуть код, так как не могу разобраться как правильно его вставлять(  вот ссылка на файл [https://yadi.sk/i/dtMlFWUD3QkYwr]
основной смысл что у меня выполняется перебор по элементам массива, и на каждом таком шаге выполняется удаление нескольких столбцов dataframe, и в конце когда кончаются столбцы у меня просто зацикливается прога

Comment: @MaxU прикрепил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [61]: d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [62]: d
Out[62]:
    a   b   c
0  36   6  16
1  77  58   0
2  91  41  45
3  31  47  62
4  73  50   2

In [63]: 'a' in d
Out[63]: True

In [64]: del d['a']

In [65]: 'a' in d
Out[65]: False

In [66]: d
Out[66]:
    b   c
0   6  16
1  58   0
2  41  45
3  47  62
4  50   2

In [67]: del d['b']

In [68]: del d['c']

In [69]: d
Out[69]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [70]: len(d.columns)
Out[70]: 0
```